# Too many sprites causing bottom sprites not to draw

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, layer, flashdevelop, overlapping

(I'm using Flashdevelop to write this in AS3)

I'm making a Pikmin-inspired 2D platformer, so naturally, I have very large amounts of Sprites on screen at once. It seems like what is happening, is that if there are any more than 23 sprites on top of each other, anything below them don't get drawn.

[Here's a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCHjj.png) of the problem. What you're seeing: The grey ball is a stack of 22 sprites. The blue background is a sprite. The shepherd-looking guy is a sprite. The left is a total of 23 sprites, and right at the shepherd is a total of 24. As you can see, the blue in that overlap (which is the bottom layer) isn't drawing, despite the alpha of all the pixels above it being zero.

Is this just a thing with Flash that I have to put up with, or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: [Here's my code](http://pastebin.com/kM3m0Ts0) Sorry I don't have enough rep to post it as multiple links. Knock yourself out.

Second Edit: I nixed all of my code, and just added a lot of plain Sprites, and the problem still happened at exactly 23 Sprites. My suspicions are confirmed in thinking that Flash can't handle that many overlapping Sprites. I'm going to play around with it and try to find a workaround.

Comment: This definitely is not an error with flash and is something on your end. Unfortunately you did not post any code so I can't give you an answer on what it is.

Comment: I'm assuming by extensions you mean inheritance (and they would all be different), I'm fairly experienced, and can tell you I can draw thousands of display objects and not have this problem. Therefore posting some code would be useful.

Comment: That's because these objects are a combination of several hundred lines of code over three different extensions, and it will be extremely difficult to pinpoint a common problem. My best bet is finding someone who has experienced this in the past and has an idea where to start looking.

Edit: Also, the objects aren't interacting with each other in any way, so in my mind, it is more likely to be something to do with how flash is handling individual bitmaps/sprites, than a mistake in something I did.

Second edit: Yes, extension == inheritance

Comment: Updated the OP with a pastebin of the relevant code. In case it's not clear, the blue in the screenshot are all Tiles, the grey balls are Wanderers, and the shepherd guy is a Player object.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you are using non-transparent bitmaps everywhere. It's most likely that your `Wanderer` skin sheet has white background at a certain frame, which is drawn instead of blue, and you are mistakingly blaming Flash engine for not drawing anything under an opaque bitmap.

Next: In `GameObject.SetSkin()` function you have `Skin = new Bitmap(skindata);`, you can do the same by assigning the `bitmapData` property of `Skin` to a new value (if it ever changes, as you are doing `copyPixels()`), so you can freely drop this, assign `Skin` once in the constructor and then go with copypaste.

Next: You have an entirely new `Bitmap` object with full skin assigned to each of the `GameObject`s, regardless of them being same class with existing objects or not. While you have little amount of objects, it might work, but once you'll hit a certain number of them, you will need to shorten memory usage or risk crashing Flash. You can use `public static var SkinSheet:Bitmap` and in constructor you do `if (!SkinSheet) SkinSheet=new ProperSkinSheet();` where `ProperSkinSheet` is the skin for the current class, be it Wanderer, Player, Tile, etc. This will make your multiple objects of the same class to use one and only skin sheet, thus reducing memory usage for your app.

Hope this helps a little.

Comment: If the Wanderer had a white bg at a certain frame (which I'm about 99% sure isn't true, since it's only 5 frames), that wouldn't explain the half-white, or how it always appears at the same number of objects. (I tested it, and it does the same with Player objects.

I fixed the line in `GameObject.SetSkin()`. Thanks for the tip.

As for making the skinsheet static, I'm not sure how well that will work with multiple object types inheriting from one class. I'm struggling with implementing it right now.

Comment: Looking through the code now, I think @Vesper is on the right track with your usage of copyPixels and not setting it with transparency. I'll have an answer soon.

Comment: So I can't confirm this without pretty having your entire project to debug through, but I believe you should try this with mergeAlpha set to true in `copyPixels()`. In your current setup whenever you `copyPixels()` I don't believe you are blitting a white background, I think you are actually clearing the pixels behind it. If you want to confirm that area is actually empty, try changing the color of the stage or put some color on the stage it and see if still draws white. I tested this locally with my own transparent textures and achieved a similar effect.

Comment: The bitmaps I'm drawing have transparent backgrounds everywhere that's not what I want showing up. When I set mergeAlpha to true, suddenly *every* object started overlapping all the others below it.

It's not an alpha problem. If it was, it would show up gradually, or every time, not suddenly at a specific and constant point.